# Dense layer not recognizing input shape even though it should

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Bottom line is that I get this error, and I've seen a few posts about it but nothing seems to be on point.

```py
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

---

I'm using `tf.data.Dataset` as my input, and it yields variable length outputs in a dictionary.
I'm using `.padded_batch` and things get padded as expected.

Each sample, is something like `{'seq_feature1': [1, 2, 3], 'seq_feature2': [5, 6], 'feature': 10}` (before batching and padding padding) - inside my network, each `seq_feature` gets embedded using `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` then concatenated and passed through an LSTM and then concatenated again to another embedded feature (no time dimension) and then into a dense layer where it all goes wrong.

This is how my forward pass looks like (the model is implemented as subclass, so this is part of the `call` method):

```py
# self.embedding1 & 2 & 3 are tf.keras.layers.Embedding
embedded_seq1 = self.embedding1(inputs['seq_feature1'])  # (batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim1)
embedded_seq2 = self.embedding2(inputs['seq_feature2'])  # (batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim2)
embedded_feat = tf.squeeze(self.embedding3(inputs['feature']))  # (batch_size, emb_dim3)

# project and pass through LSTM
x = tf.concat([embedded_seq1, embedded_seq2], axis=-1)
x = self.dense1(x)  # <-- Works as expected, (batch_size, seq_len, dense1_units)
x = self.lstm(x)  # (batch_size, lstm_units)

# concat pass through Dense
x = tf.concat([x, embedded_feat, axis=-1)  # (batch_size, lstm_units + emb_dim3)

# ERROR GETS THROWN HERE
x = self.dense2(x)
```

Last line throws the `ValueError` mentioned before, which doesn't make any sense. I can calculate the last dimension of the input, and I validated it using eager execution and running through the layers one by one (which works without error, the error only fails when running it all at once).

What am I missing here?

**actual code uses masking in LSTM but irrelevant for post I guess*

---

#### EDIT

I can avoid this error if I explicitly call the `self.dense2.build(tf.TensorShape([None, <the_number_i_can_calculate_but_tf_cant>]))` but since I can easily calculate it using the `lstm_units + emb_dim3` it is still a bug and I can't understand why it happens

Answer (score 0):

This error might be triggered because the output shape of the generator is not passed to the model first layers, in your case it is the embedding layers. I had similar problem which I solved with a workaround. For each input you should init the shape manually:

```
my_model._layers[0]._batch_input_shape= my_geneartor.element_spec[0].shape
my_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(my_model.to_json()) #rebuilding the model
```

It works on tf version 2.1.